# Python regex match all sentences include either wordA or wordB

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I'm trying to find all sentences include either 'play' or 'improve' in a document.

my current pattern is like this

```
pattern = re.compile('(?<=[ |\.])[\w ]*?play\w+.*?\.') 
// start from " " or "." meaning the beginning of a sentence. 
// then some words and " ", as least as possible, 
// then all formats of "play" (played, playing)
```

My issue is I don't know how to include "either or" in the pattern.

I thought it should be

```
pattern = re.compile('(?<=[ |\.])[\w ]*?[play|improv]\w+.*?\.')
```

But that is not correct.

Comment: `[play|improv]` => `(play|improv)` or `(?:play|improv)`

Comment: [abc] stands for a character set containing a,b and c.